# Injected script fails when using dynamic route in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently injecting a script into my React App from my public folder using the following logic

```
const status = useScript('./tagging.js')
console.log(status)
```

The useScript hook handles the script injection and returns a status of either loading, ready or error.  The useScript hook looks like the following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const useScript = (url) => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(url ? 'loading' : 'idle')
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) {
      setStatus('idle')
      return
    }

    let script = document.querySelector(`script[src="${url}"]`)

    if (!script) {
      script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = url
      script.type = 'text/javascript'
      script.async = true

      document.head.appendChild(script)

      const setAttributeFromEvent = (event) => {
        script.setAttribute(
          'data-status',
          event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error'
        )
      }

      script.addEventListener('load', setAttributeFromEvent)
      script.addEventListener('error', setAttributeFromEvent)
    } else {
      setStatus(script.getAttribute('data-status'))
    }

    const setStateFromEvent = (event) => {
      setStatus(event.type === 'load' ? 'ready' : 'error')
    }

    script.addEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
    script.addEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)

    return () => {
      if (script) {
        script.removeEventListener('load', setStateFromEvent)
        script.removeEventListener('error', setStateFromEvent)
      }
    }
  }, [url, location])

  return status
}

export default useScript
```

I am noticing, that the above code works for injecting a script into my react app when using a standard route within react-router-dom.  When using a dynamic route; however, the script injection comes back with a status of ready but fails to load the script altogether and returns the following error:

```
Unexpected token '<'
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

When inspecting the head of my react app, I see the script loaded into the head, but it appears to fail to load the script source properly on dynamic routes for some reason.

Here is how I set up my dynamic routes for reference:

```
   <Routes>
      <Route path='/offer' element={<Offer />} />
      <Route path='/hearing-agency' element={<HearingAgency />} />
      <Route
        path='/hearing-agency/brand/:brandname'
        element={<HearingAgency />}
      />
      <Route path='/survey' element={<Survey windowSize={windowSize} />} />
      <Route
        path='/hearing-screener'
        element={<HearingScreener windowSize={windowSize} />}
      />
      <Route path='/product' element={<Product />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<Offer />} />
    </Routes>
```

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Attached is a codesandbox for testing https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wood-rcsfni?file=/src/Pages/StandardRoute.js

The way to test.  hit the standard route and notice the console log is loading the dummy script.  Then append /brand/phonak to the end of the url and notice the script fails and the error boundary for React appears citing the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you make a reproducable example in here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: I can't really provide the script but let me see if I can find a dummy script and create a sandbox for it

Comment: @PauloFernando updated with code sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the URL passed to useScript is a relative URl, and it will change based on the route:

Dynamic Route:
https://prnt.sc/p_T-4m4fyvVE

Standard Route:
https://prnt.sc/fJQPZfbToC0j

You can just remove the `.` so that is always uses the base URL:

```
useScript("/dummyscript.js");
```

Comment: okay I believe that makes sense let me test it out, and does it need to be an absolute url in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Hehehe, actually now i thought better, just remove the `.`

Comment: lol massive facepalm on my part... I guess im wondering why the /tagging.js works regardless of dynamic vs standard

Comment: ah i see you explained in the updated answer, much appreciated!